# What is the formula of WIDTH in this scenario?

Tags: c#, xml, rect

I have a task where i need to create a conversion program from OmniPage XML ocr output into ALTO XML.

The output of OmniPage XML is really different from ALTO XML.

I tried to find an ALTO XML file and trying to figure out where those values came from.

I need to get the formula of SP Tag WIDTH.
Below is the sample XML i'm trying to figure out

```
<TextLine ID="P1_TL00002" HPOS="26.00" VPOS="98.00" WIDTH="1667.00" HEIGHT="130.00">
    <String ID="P1_ST00002" HPOS="26.00" VPOS="106.00" WIDTH="387.00" HEIGHT="95.00" CONTENT="Twenties" WC="0.99" CC="06370005"/>
    <SP ID="P1_SP00001" HPOS="413.00" VPOS="201.00" WIDTH="29.00"/>
    <String ID="P1_ST00003" HPOS="442.00" VPOS="98.00" WIDTH="246.00" HEIGHT="103.00" CONTENT="Glrls" WC="0.78" CC="00045"/>
    <SP ID="P1_SP00002" HPOS="688.00" VPOS="201.00" WIDTH="26.00"/>
    <String ID="P1_ST00004" HPOS="714.00" VPOS="98.00" WIDTH="178.00" HEIGHT="103.00" CONTENT="ancl" WC="0.54" CC="5660"/>
    <SP ID="P1_SP00003" HPOS="892.00" VPOS="201.00" WIDTH="39.00"/>
    <String ID="P1_ST00005" HPOS="931.00" VPOS="98.00" WIDTH="368.00" HEIGHT="130.00" CONTENT="FUppER" WC="0.83" CC="090000"/>
    <SP ID="P1_SP00004" HPOS="1299.00" VPOS="228.00" WIDTH="32.00"/>
    <String ID="P1_ST00006" HPOS="1331.00" VPOS="98.00" WIDTH="362.00" HEIGHT="106.00" CONTENT="PAshiON" WC="0.76" CC="0008206"/>
</TextLine>
```

I already figured out the values of HPOS and VPOS. 
I used c# `Rect` class

```
Rect r = new Rect(26, 106, 387, 95);
Debug.WriteLine("BottomRight: " + r.BottomRight);
BottomRight: 413,201
```

But I can't figure where the `SP` tag's `WIDTH` value comes from.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it’s just the difference between the SP tags HPOS and the following String tags HPOS, e.g. 413.00 + 29.00 = 442.00, 688.00 + 26.00 = 714.00, and so on.